# Kotlin Regex: How to get the group name in a MatchResult

Tags: regex, kotlin

I'd like to link the MatchResults of a RegEx with named groups back to the group names, so that I can tell which group(s) which caused that match.

A Kotlin code example:

```
        val name = "my name@some-value"

        val matchResults = """(?<word>\p{L}+)|(?<sep>[^\p{L}]+)"""
                           .toRegex()
                           .findAll(name)

        matchResults.forEach {
            println("'${it.value}' is a ${it.groupname}}")
        }
```

The problem with the code above is that it does not compile (there is no `groupname` in the MatchResult class). I could not find a way to get the name(s) of the group(s) which caused a specific MatchResult.

I would like the code above to generate the following output:

```
        'my' is a word
        ' ' is a sep
        'name' is a word
        '@' is a sep
        'some' is a word
        '-' is a sep
        'value' is a word
```

I'd like the results to stay in the same order in which they were in the input string, so that I can call `.map {}` and then handle words and separators differently, and then reconstruct the sentence.

I am using Kotlin 1.8.0, targeting JDK 11. I know that for this combination the RegEx library does support named groups, but the MatchResults don't contain any reference back to the named group.

Comment: Why not use two different regexps to achieve what you want? If you have a `my name@some-value` string as input, what should be the end result?

Comment: The Kotlin Regex api doesn't seem to expose named groups. You could use the Java api, [which does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28java.lang.String%29) support them.

Comment: Different regex is not an option, i want to have a stream of "typed words" so that I can handle each part in the same order as they appeared, hence my example with the forEach. If that forEach works as in my question, the question is answered.
I know that the java API has named groups, but as far as I checked the MatchResults does not refer back to which group name resulted in this match.

Comment: Did you forget to say what isn't working with what you have?  What output are you seeing? Is there an error?

Comment: Those are good points, I'll fix that in my question, thanks Linda!

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to connect a match results of a RegEx to the named group which caused the matchresult. The way I solved this problem is by splitting the regex into the groups and doing extra matches to find which group matches:

```
    // Named regex groups separately stored in a map:
    val typeRegexes = mapOf (
        "word" to """(?<word>\p{L}+)""".toRegex(),
        "separator" to """(?<sep>[^\p{L}]+)""".toRegex()
    )

    // Simple function to see which regex group matches (first match wins)
    fun getTypeOf(string:String) :String =
        typeRegexes.entries.firstOrNull {
           it.value.matches(string) 
        }?.key ?: "unknown"

    // Combine all regex groups into a single regex so we have a
    // stream of ordered matchresults
    val combinedRegex = typeRegexes.values
                            .map { it.pattern }
                            .joinToString("|").toRegex()

    // The value to test (as in the original question)
    val name = "my name@some-value"
    
    // All match results in the correct order
    val matchResults = combinedRegex.findAll(name)
    
    // For each match result, do a second match on each group to print the type:
    matchResults.forEach {
        println("'${it.value}' is a ${getTypeOf(it.value)}")
    }
```

If there is a more optimal way to do this please share your answer, thanks!